# How do I 301 redirect these route changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a couple routes like this:

```
  match ':category/:brand/:permalink' => 'products#show', :as => :public_product
  match 'stoves' => 'home#stoves', :as => :stoves
```

I changed them to this:

```
  match ':category/:brand/:permalink' => 'products#show', :as => :public_product
  match 'wood_stoves' => 'home#wood_stoves', :as => :stoves
```

I changed the category record titled `stoves` to `wood_stoves`.

Can I add a route redirect that allows for wildcards that would change anything like `domain.com/stoves` or `domain.com/stoves/morso/8140-contemporary` to `domain.com/wood_stoves` or `domain.com/wood_stoves/morso/8140-contemporary`, respectively? Or should I put this in my apache virtualhost config block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your route.rb to be like this:

```
match ':category/:brand/:permalink' => 'products#show', :as => :public_product
match 'stoves' => 'home#stoves', :as => :old_stoves # anything else except stoves
match 'wood_stoves' => 'home#wood_stoves', :as => :stoves
```

In your Home Controller:

```
def stove
  redirect_to stoves_path(# Use parameters here when a user hits a link like domain.com/stoves or domain.com/stoves/morso/8140-contemporary)
end
def wood_stoves
  # your code here..
end
```

Comment: I'm hoping for a single solution to catch both the old home#stoves action and the products#show action.

Comment: I'm doing a variant of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
match ':category/:brand/:permalink' => 'products#show', :as => :public_product
match 'stoves' => 'home#stoves', :as => :old_stoves # 
match 'wood_stoves' => 'home#stoves', :as => :stoves
```

This is enough i think.

If you are so particular about to change the name of the action to wood_stoves then i think you need to do Surya's solution